# AttributeError: module 'guidedlda' has no attribute '_guidedlda'

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I am using the [GuidedLDA library](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA) which is a modified version of LDA on my Windows 10 machine with Python 3.6 in Jupyter Notebook. The packages have the following structure:
[Pacakge Folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ2dj.png)

Since the _guidedlda.c file is written in Cython, I am getting the following error in the import stage itself.

```
AttributeError: module 'guidedlda' has no attribute '_guidedlda'
```

Would be great if anyone could help.

Comment: Does this happen when you compile or during runtime?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DibloDk The error occurs right at the import stage itself.

Comment: It may be a good idea to update your post with where when it happens and a code preview. - It can be difficult to back track without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix (not really a fix, just a way around) myself:

Use Microsoft Visual Studio Code and not Jupyter/PyCharm or any other editors. VS Code supports C and C++ build tools well.

I would recommend creating a new Python 3.6 virtual environment in VS Code solely for using this guidedLDA library.